# Form of `hidden_states` for Mamba architecture

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I'm playing around with the recent Mamba architecture using the HuggingFace implementation. It has the form

```
MambaForCausalLM(
  (backbone): MambaModel(
    (embeddings): Embedding(50280, 768)
    (layers): ModuleList(
      (0-23): 24 x MambaBlock(
        (norm): MambaRMSNorm()
        (mixer): MambaMixer(
          (conv1d): Conv1d(1536, 1536, kernel_size=(4,), stride=(1,), padding=(3,), groups=1536)
          (act): SiLU()
          (in_proj): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=False)
          (x_proj): Linear(in_features=1536, out_features=80, bias=False)
          (dt_proj): Linear(in_features=48, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (out_proj): Linear(in_features=1536, out_features=768, bias=False)
        )
      )
    )
    (norm_f): MambaRMSNorm()
  )
  (lm_head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=50280, bias=False)
)
```

and when I take the model `outputs.hidden_state` after passing in a dummy input sentence, it has length `25`. To me, this means the first entry is the output from `model.backbone.embeddings`, and the rest are from the `24` layers in the backbone, with nothing from the `lm_head`. So I imagine that changing the LM head (eg, by replacing it with a random matrix) should have no effect on `outputs.hidden_state[-1]`, which I imagine to be the output from `model.backbone.layers[-1]`, even though it will obviously affect `outputs.logits`. However, `outputs.hidden_state[-1]` changes dramatically when I do this. Why is this? When I add a hook to track activations from each of the `24` layers by hand, the final activation does not change with changes to `lm_head`, as I would expect. So I guess `outputs.hidden_states` contains something different to what I thought. What's going on here? Thank you!